# BLE Puck.js nobleJs - Get advertising data

Tags: node.js, bluetooth-lowenergy

Im using PuckJS to advertise some data. As an example I try to advertise the current temperature like so

```
    setInterval(function() {
      digitalPulse(LED3,true,500);
      NRF.setAdvertising(
        {
        0x1809 : [Math.round(E.getTemperature())]
      },
        {
        manufacturer:0x0590,
        manufacturerData:"Moin"
      }
        );
    }, 1000);
```

On my Mac I use [noble](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@abandonware/noble) for receiving the data.
What I want to archive is, that every time the Tokens sends an update (every 1000ms) the current temperature is logged.
But all I ever receive is "Data <- Serial1" on my console. Also the on("data") event handler is never called.
This is what the code looks like

```
import noble from "@abandonware/noble";

noble.on("stateChange", async (state) => {
  if (state === "poweredOn") {
    await noble.startScanningAsync(false);
  }
});

noble.on("discover", async (peripheral) => {
  if (peripheral.id !== "7515300cdefc6fee0cf2d840f8e4a9cf") {
    return;
  }

  console.log(
    "Manufacturer Data: ",
    peripheral.advertisement.manufacturerData.toString()
  );

  await noble.stopScanningAsync();

  await peripheral.connectAsync();

  const { characteristics, services } =
    await peripheral.discoverAllServicesAndCharacteristicsAsync();

  console.log(services);
  console.log(characteristics);

  await characteristics[0].notifyAsync(true);

  characteristics[0].on("data", (data, isNotify) => {
    console.log("Data", data.toString());
  });

  //await peripheral.disconnectAsync();
  //process.exit(0);
});
```

And this is the output on my console

```
Manufacturer Data:  �Moin
[
  Service {
    _noble: Noble {
      initialized: true,
      address: 'unknown',
      _state: 'poweredOn',
      _bindings: [NobleMac],
      _peripherals: [Object],
      _services: [Object],
      _characteristics: [Object],
      _descriptors: [Object],
      _discoveredPeripheralUUids: [Array],
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 4,
      _allowDuplicates: undefined
    },
    _peripheralId: '7515300cdefc6fee0cf2d840f8e4a9cf',
    uuid: '6e400001b5a3f393e0a9e50e24dcca9e',
    name: null,
    type: null,
    includedServiceUuids: null,
    characteristics: [ [Characteristic], [Characteristic] ],
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
    _eventsCount: 0
  }
]
[
  Characteristic {
    _noble: Noble {
      initialized: true,
      address: 'unknown',
      _state: 'poweredOn',
      _bindings: [NobleMac],
      _peripherals: [Object],
      _services: [Object],
      _characteristics: [Object],
      _descriptors: [Object],
      _discoveredPeripheralUUids: [Array],
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 4,
      _allowDuplicates: undefined
    },
    _peripheralId: '7515300cdefc6fee0cf2d840f8e4a9cf',
    _serviceUuid: '6e400001b5a3f393e0a9e50e24dcca9e',
    uuid: '6e400003b5a3f393e0a9e50e24dcca9e',
    name: null,
    type: null,
    properties: [ 'notify' ],
    descriptors: null
  },
  Characteristic {
    _noble: Noble {
      initialized: true,
      address: 'unknown',
      _state: 'poweredOn',
      _bindings: [NobleMac],
      _peripherals: [Object],
      _services: [Object],
      _characteristics: [Object],
      _descriptors: [Object],
      _discoveredPeripheralUUids: [Array],
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 4,
      _allowDuplicates: undefined
    },
    _peripheralId: '7515300cdefc6fee0cf2d840f8e4a9cf',
    _serviceUuid: '6e400001b5a3f393e0a9e50e24dcca9e',
    uuid: '6e400002b5a3f393e0a9e50e24dcca9e',
    name: null,
    type: null,
    properties: [ 'writeWithoutResponse', 'write' ],
    descriptors: null
  }
]
Data <- Serial1
>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution.
I think I misunderstood how things are working. For anyone else who tries to understand, here my solution as a reference.

### Puck.js / Espruino

First, you have to define and set the service and characteristics itself. This can be a custom service / characteristic with a self defined UUID or an already registered service id from [here](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/assigned-numbers/).

A service is defined by the [NRF.setService](https://www.espruino.com/Reference#l_NRF_setServices) method

```
NRF.setServices({
  "b7920001-3c1b-4b40-869f-3c0db9be80c6" : {
    "c7920001-3c1b-4b40-869f-3c0db9be80c6" : {
      value : String(Puck.getTemperature()),
      maxLen : 20,
      broadcast : false, // optional, default is false
      readable : true,   // optional, default is false
      writable : true,   // optional, default is false
      onWrite : function(evt) {
        digitalWrite([LED3,LED2,LED1], evt.data[0]);
      },
      notify : true,   // optional, default is false
      indicate : true,   // optional, default is false
      description: "My Characteristic",  // optional, default is null,
    }
  }
});
```

The service must be readable!

This is basically enough to get the service running. However, if you try to connect to a device with a specific service from a client, you have to advertise that this service is available on your device. This is done by the [NRF.setAdvertising](https://www.espruino.com/Reference#l_NRF_setAdvertising) method. This will make the BT device and the service discoverable for any client that wants to connect:

```
NRF.setAdvertising({
  "b7920001-3c1b-4b40-869f-3c0db9be80c6" : undefined
});
```

I wanted the value of the characteristic to be updated on a time interval. Therefore, you use the [NRF.updateService](https://www.espruino.com/Reference#l_NRF_updateServices) method.

```
setInterval(()=>{
  NRF.updateServices({
    "b7920001-3c1b-4b40-869f-3c0db9be80c6" : {
      "c7920001-3c1b-4b40-869f-3c0db9be80c6" : {
        value : String(Puck.getTemperature()),
        notify: true,
        readable:true
      }
    }
  });
}, 5000);
```

This will update the service with the current temperature every 5 seconds.

> Note: You must define the `notify : true` value in the setService method. Otherwise this service will not be updatable.

> Note 2: You have to wrap the value into the string method. Otherwise the values will not be visible on the client.

### NodeJs

Now you can use the noble package as described in the documentation.
Here a working example.

```
import noble from "@abandonware/noble";

noble.on("stateChange", async (state) => {
  if (state === "poweredOn") {
    console.log("Start scanning...");
    await noble.startScanningAsync(
      ["b7920001-3c1b-4b40-869f-3c0db9be80c6"],
      false
    );
  }
});

noble.on("discover", async (peripheral) => {
  console.log("Found Device", peripheral.advertisement.localName);

  await noble.stopScanningAsync();

  await peripheral.connectAsync();

  peripheral.on("disconnect", (err) => {
    console.log("Device is disconnected", err);
    process.exit(0);
  });

  const { characteristics } =
    await peripheral.discoverSomeServicesAndCharacteristicsAsync(
      ["b7920001-3c1b-4b40-869f-3c0db9be80c6"],
      ["c7920001-3c1b-4b40-869f-3c0db9be80c6"]
    );

  const char = characteristics[0];
  characteristics[0].on("data", async (data, isNotify) => {
    console.log(data.toString());
  });

  await char.subscribeAsync();
});
```

### Web / React

You can also use the Bluethooth API available in Chrome.

Here an React example App.tsx.

> If you work with TypeScript, install the [@types/web-bluetooth](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/web-bluetooth) package, or you will have a lot of ES errors in your code.

```
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  const handleBtDeviceRequest = async () => {
    const device = await navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice({
      filters: [
        {
          services: ["b7920001-3c1b-4b40-869f-3c0db9be80c6"],
        },
      ],
    });

    const server = await device.gatt?.connect();

    const service = await server?.getPrimaryService(
      "b7920001-3c1b-4b40-869f-3c0db9be80c6"
    );

    if (!service) {
      console.log("No services found");
      return;
    }

    const char = await service.getCharacteristic(
      "c7920001-3c1b-4b40-869f-3c0db9be80c6"
    );

    char.addEventListener("characteristicvaluechanged", (ev) => {
      var enc = new TextDecoder("utf-8");
      //@ts-ignore
      console.log(enc.decode(ev.currentTarget.value));
    });

    await char.startNotifications();
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={handleBtDeviceRequest}>Press me</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Hope this will help someone else!